# stiff textile material for simple underbed "drawer"

Tags: carpet, bedroom, storage, drawers, ground

I have a 90cm x 200cm bed in a corner of my room. I want to use the floor beneath it as storage, but in a way that I do not need to crawl under it to get the stuff in the corner. I have a PVC floor; textiles generally slide well on it - e.g. bed sheets, socks, or carpets without anti-slide coating.

**Is there any type of textile (e.g. carpet) that is so stiff that it can be both drawn and pushed back without losing its form? Or is there a simple way of making such a thing?**

I would put that thing under the bed and my stuff to store on top. No heavy things; just bedclothes, blankets and clothes inside light boxes and bags. Then I could use it as a simple drawer and the need to crawl under the bed would be gone.

Comment: Cardboard?   posterboard (as used for kids' science fair displays)?

Comment: you can buy plastic storage boxes that have wheels and are designed to fit under a bed ... https://media.4rgos.it/i/Argos/9051036_R_Z001A_UC1176666?$Web$&w=570&h=513

Comment: Just use thin plywood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PVC sheets may be a great option. You can use a thicker one that will hold it's shape better or a thin one that can be rolled up. [Here](https://www.tapplastics.com/product/plastics/cut_to_size_plastic/pvc_sheets/531) is one of many suppliers just to give an example.

Personally, I'm a frugal and more about problem solving than how it looks and would probably use cardboard. I'd either use a bigger box from home delivery items or hunt down a large one, a household appliance store would have plenty of large and thick cardboard from such things as refrigerators. It's probably ok to just dumpster dive in the their recycle bin in the back but the best thing to do is ask up front.

Another option is plywood on furniture sliders and they come in square shape which would work very well too

[image]
pic credit: wayfair.com